# 5 people line up with their arms connected, and they all run in a circle with the center person standing still. How do the tensions compare?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

If we have 5 people with their arms connected, and they all revolve around the center person with the same period length, each person will have a different velocity and acceleration with the outside person having the highest of both. The centripetal force is made up of a friction force from the person running, but also a tension force from the person on their inside. In my physics class’ experiment, the outside people let go of the persons arm before sliding out, which implies that the friction could withstand but they could not maintain the tension. Is it accurate then that tension is the greatest at the end of the chain?

So far I have that the centripetal force for each person is Ftension(person on inside) + Ffriction - Ftension(person on outside).

The only problem with my thinking is that when I modeled this, I found that tension should be the greatest at the center which intuitively doesn’t seem likely since the center person has no problems holding on.

My overall questions are: Is the tension between two people highest at the outside or inside of the chain? And what causes the outside person to break off while the inside people can stay on?

My teacher said she wasn’t entirely sure and told me to let her know what I find out.

Comment: Have you first considered the case of where there is no friction?

Comment: Interesting. That adds to why I think intuitively that tension should be highest at the ends; if there is a greater acceleration then there must be a greater force. And since tension would be the only force, tension must increase for each person added to the chain.

Comment: In the "experiment", was everyone staying in a line, or did the ends last behind making more of a whip?

Comment: Here's something to flip your intuition around. Assuming the idealized case, from the reference frame of the center person, there is a *centrifugal* (outward) force on the chain; this is kind of like artificial gravity pointing down the chain. So, picture the central person having to hold on to a chain of people hanging down a cliff. Flipping this around, the centripetal force has to accelerate *a chain of people* (= more mass). But as BioPhysicist points out, in real life, you probably don't have an idealized situation; they are also supported by the ground, and that complicates things.

Answer (score 1):

For the theory, just model this as spinning a rope from one end.

Take a rope of uniform linear mass density $\lambda=\text dm/\text dr$ and rotate it about its end with angular speed $\omega$. For a given section of rope with mass $\text dm$ located a distance $r$ from the center of rotation, it has a force $T$ acting towards the center of rotation and a force $T+\text dT$ acting outwards. Since this section of the rope is undergoing circular motion, it must be that

$$T+\text dT-T=-(\lambda\,\text dr)\omega^2r$$

This can be easily integrated to find the tension $T$ along the rope relative to the tension $T_0$ at the center

$$\int_{T_0}^{T}\text dT'=\int_0^r\lambda\omega^2r'\,\text dr'$$
$$T=T_0-\frac12\lambda\omega^2r^2$$

And so we see that the tension decreases as you move away from the center of rotation.

---

Looking at the "experiment", you say the people on the ends let go first. This is probably because the people on the outside need to run faster in order to keep up with the circular motion. What likely happened is that the people on the end started lagging behind, and thus they were getting pulled on by the people on the inside in order to keep up. This means the "rope" is no longer straight, and hence the extra curvature brings along with it extra tension.

What you have here is kind of like the game [crack the whip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crack_the_whip)

> One player, chosen as the "head" of the whip, runs (or skates) around in random directions, with subsequent players holding on to the hand of the previous player. The entire "tail" of the whip moves in those directions but with much more force toward the end of the tail. The longer the tail, the more the forces act on the last player and the tighter they have to hold on.

Answer (score 0):

> My overall questions are: Is the tension between two people highest at the outside or inside of the chain? And what causes the outside person to break off while the inside people can stay on?

As said by @BioPhysicist I will first consider the case where there is no friction.
Suppose you have 3 balls each of mass $m$ tied with each other at a distance $r$ as shown here. And the system is rotating with angular velocity $\omega$. (Sorry for bad quality as I couldn't find any appropriate tool for this.)
[image]
So $T_1$ acts along OA and to balance the forces $$T_1 = F_1 + F_2+F_3 = m\omega^2r+m\omega^22r+m\omega^23r$$ $$T_1 = 6m\omega^2r$$ Similarly for $T_2$ , $$T_2 = F_2 + F_3 = 5m\omega^2r$$ and $T_3$ , $$T_3 = F_3 = 3m\omega^2r$$
And this shows that the tension is greatest as the centre as you said.
Now if we consider friction it will act in the same direction of $T_1$ and since $F_1,F_2,F_3$ are centrifugal forces therefore they are constant and thus the friction will help in reducing the tension. But I don't think so that the outside person should break of because it doesn't seem to be true **mathematically**.
It was a really interesting question.
Hope it helps. :)